# CloudFormation deploy Method already exists for this resource

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have a CloudFormation template that creates an APIGateway, but when I deploy again to add APIGateway methods (running update stack) I get:

```
Method already exists for this resource (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 409; 
Error Code: ConflictException; Request ID: 7058deed-14e1-46bc-863d-efba23cd668b; Proxy: null)
```

I attempted to add an update/delete policy to all resources but that doesn't seem to have worked:

```
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
```

I have a hunch it may be caused by not specifying the resources correctly, do I have something wrong with my resource paths? Are both resources being created at the root resource or something?

**My End Goal**

To declare two separate resources (with seperate URLS) eg

https://xxx/post-note

https://xxx/deleteNote

that are both tied to lambda functions

**My template:**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
# above two lines necessary to convert SAM template to CloudFormation template
Description: Resource definitions for my site
Globals: # any parameters you want available to all your resources
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'OPTIONS,POST,GET'"
      AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"

  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs14.x # language used at runtime
    Timeout: 35 # timeout seconds for a given lambda function execution
    Environment:
      Variables: # these will be important later
        DYNAMO_TABLE: !Ref DynamoNotesTable
        DB_ENDPOINT: http://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
        REGION_NAME: us-east-1

Resources:
  # #############################################################################
  # # BACK END LAMBDAS
  # #############################################################################
  postNote:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: backend/dynamo/postNote.postNote
      CodeUri: s3://backend/xxx
      Policies:
        - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess

  deleteNote:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: backend/dynamo/deleteNote.deleteNote
      CodeUri: s3://backend/xxx
      Policies:
        - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess

  #############################################################################
  # api-gateway (with cognito auth)
  # https://bl.ocks.org/magnetikonline/c314952045eee8e8375b82bc7ec68e88
  #############################################################################
  apiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Description: API Gateway
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL
      Name: my-api

  postNoteGatewayMethod:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: POST
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub
          - arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt postNote.Arn
      ResourceId: !GetAtt apiGateway.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway

  deleteNoteGatewayMethod:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: POST
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub
          - arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt deleteNote.Arn
      ResourceId: !GetAtt apiGateway.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway

  apiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn:
      - postNoteGatewayMethod
      - deleteNoteGatewayMethod
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      StageName: Prod

  lambdaApiGatewayInvoke:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt postNote.Arn
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Sub arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiGateway}/Prod/POST/PATH_PART
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both cloudformation resources `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` pointing to same api gateway resource with same method POST.

We have two options

Option 1: Change Method Name for one of the methods.

```
  deleteNoteGatewayMethod:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: POST   <--- should be DELETE
      AuthorizationType: "NONE"
```

Option 2: have a different root resource for each methods. so, if we need two POST endpoints /postNote and /deleteNote, we must have two separate resources from the root path and use these resources for the lambdas.

Ex:

`/postNote` with Parent as root resource.

```
  noteResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt apiGateway.RootResourceId
      PathPart: "postNote"
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
```

and method `ResourceId` pointing to `!Ref noteResource`

```
  postNoteGatewayMethod:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    DependsOn:
      - noteResource
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: POST
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub
          - arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt postNote.Arn
      ResourceId: !Ref noteResource
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
```

Similarly we need to add delete resource.

```
  deleteResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt apiGateway.RootResourceId
      PathPart: "deleteNote"
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway

  deleteNoteGatewayMethod:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    DependsOn:
      - deleteResource
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: POST
      AuthorizationType: "NONE"
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub
          - arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt deleteNote.Arn
      ResourceId: !Ref deleteResource
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but I am trying to To declare two separate resources (with seperate URLS) like: https://xxx/post-note AND https://xxx/deleteNote 

I updated my post to hopefully make this clearer

Comment: Got it! we then need to two different resources, let me try and update the answer.

Comment: I updated answer with details about creating different resources for each method.